# Return different <Input> in a form using a switch to return the Input

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, input

I'm trying to achieve a Form where first you see 2  and then when you click a button, you see other Input.
I'm using a switch where based on a value I return the first 2  or the others.
I've tried returning only the , returning a form with the inputs but everything gives me the same problem. After i fill the first two text input, when i switch to the others, the first 2 of those input has the values of the previous 2 input.

Thanks for your help.

Here there is a basic version of the code

```
function renderSwitch() {
  switch (currentPhase) {
    case 0:
      return (
        <div>
          <input name='email' type='email' placeholder='Inserisci email' />
        </div>
      );
      break;

    case 1:
      return (
        <div>
          <input
            name='surname'
            type='text'
            placeholder='Inserisci Cognome...'
          />
        </div>
      );
      break;
  }

  return (
    <div
      className='registerpage'
      style={{ height: '100vh', backgroundColor: 'white' }}
    >
      <div className='formdiv'>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          {renderSwitch()}

          {currentPhase < 1 && (
            <button onClick={() => nextPhase()}>Next</button>
          )}
          {currentPhase > 0 && (
            <button onClick={() => previousPhase()}>Back</button>
          )}
          <br />
          <button type='submit'>Iscriviti</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi VondeTaconadis, I'm not sure I understand - are you trying to change the values of the fields and keep them that way? Is that the problem?

Comment: I want to have different inputs that keep the value of the user, but I don't want to show all of the Input at the same time. The problem is that when I return a different <Input> the value of the previous <Input> is inside the <Input> I've just return

Comment: It sounds like you want to use state - this is a basic concept of React that you should definitely read up before trying to jump into the deep end. Luca Pizzini did give you the answer you can copy and paste, but I highly recommend reading up a bit more so that you understand the basic concepts first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store the input values using a state:

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
const [surname, setSurname] = useState('')

function renderSwitch() {
    switch (currentPhase) {
      case 0:
        return (
          <div>
            <input value={email} name='email' type='email' placeholder='Inserisci email' />
          </div>
        );
        break;
  
      case 1:
        return (
          <div>
            <input
            value={surname}
              name='surname'
              type='text'
              placeholder='Inserisci Cognome...'
            />
          </div>
        );
        break;
    }
}
```

And then reset them once you have submitted your data:

```
function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    // Handler your data...

    setEmail('')
    setSurname('')
}
```